# Problem in reading data from a var and pass it to other one in C

Tags: c, malloc, allocation

I'm trying to create a 3D Game Using C.
but I have a problem in The following Code

**explain The Code**

I have a file named 1.cub (lock down the code), this file has The map.
using The function `read_cf_color` I read The color of The floor and The sky from The 1.cub file and store The floor color in var named `mlx->floor_color`, and The ceiling in var named `mlx->sky_color`.
P.S: using some other functions I read all The data from 1.cub and store it in var named `mlx->lines`.

`parse_parameters` : scan all The data in `mlx->lines` (1.cub file) and send every line to `choose_param`.

`choose_param`: get The line from `parse_parameters` and tey to match every `c` with the right function.

`read_cf_color`: This function gets the color of the floor/ceiling. and cast it from `char *` to `long int`.

`ft_isfloor`: get the color from the previous function and give it to the right var (`mlx->floor_color`/`mlx->sky->color`).

for example:

> `parse_parameters` pass this line `F 100    ,   100   ,   214` to `choose_param`.
>
> Then `choose_param` pass The `F` To `char c` in `read_cf_color` and the rest  `100    ,   100   ,   214` to `char *s`.
>
> the function try to make this  `100    ,   100   ,   214` look like this `100100214` and store it in `long int color`

```
int     choose_param(char c, char *str, t_mlx *mlx)
{
    while (*str == ' ')
        str++;
    if (c == 'R' && *(str + 1) == ' ')
        read_resolution(str + 1, mlx);
    else if (c == 'N' && *(str + 1) == 'O' && *(str + 2) == ' ')
        read_txt(1, str + 2, mlx);
    else if (c == 'S' && *(str + 1) == 'O' && *(str + 2) == ' ')
        read_txt(2, str + 2, mlx);
    else if (c == 'W' && *(str + 1) == 'E' && *(str + 2) == ' ')
        read_txt(4, str + 2, mlx);
    else if (c == 'E' && *(str + 1) == 'A' && *(str + 2) == ' ')
        read_txt(3, str + 2, mlx);
    else if (c == 'F' && *(str + 1) == ' ')
        read_cf_color(str + 1, mlx, 'f');
    else if (c == 'C' && *(str + 1) == ' ')
        read_cf_color(str + 1, mlx, 'c');
    else if (c == 'S' && *(str + 1) == ' ')
        read_txt(5, str + 1, mlx);
    else if (c == '1' || c == '0' || c == '2')
        return (0);
    else if (c)
        ft_put_error("NON-EMPTY LINE WITH WRONG IDENTIFIER\n", mlx);
    return (1);
}

char    **parse_parameters(t_mlx *mlx, char **lines)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int map;

    i = 0;
    map = 0;
    while (lines[i])
    {
        j = 0;
        while (lines[i][j] == ' ')
            j++;
        if (!choose_param(lines[i][j], lines[i], mlx))
        {
            return (&lines[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    ft_put_error("NO MAP FOUND\n", mlx);
    return (lines);
}
void    ft_isfloor(char *s, t_mlx *mlx, char type, char *stor)
{
    if (type == 'f')
    {
        ft_printf("The rest of The floor:\t|%s|\n",s);
        extra_param(s, mlx, "Too many Floor rgb inputs");
        mlx->floor_color = ft_atoi(stor);
        ft_printf("The floor Value: |%d|\n",mlx->floor_color);
        if (mlx->floor_color < 0)
            ft_put_error("Wrong values for floor color\n", mlx);
        mlx->floor_done = 1;
    }
    else if (type == 'c')
    {
        ft_printf("The rest of The ceiling\t\n|%s|\n",s);
        extra_param(s, mlx, "Too many ceiling rgb inputs");
        mlx->sky_color = ft_atoi(stor);
        ft_printf("The ceiling Value: |%d|\n",mlx->sky_color);
        if (mlx->floor_color < 0)
            ft_put_error("Wrong values for ceiling color\n", mlx);
        mlx->sky_done = 1;
    }
}

void    read_cf_color(char *s, t_mlx *mlx, char type)
{
    long int    color;
    char        *stor;
    int         i;

    i = 3;
    
    color = 0;
    if (mlx->floor_done && type == 'f')
        ft_put_error("Multiple floor color inputs\n", mlx);
    if (mlx->sky_done && type == 'c')
        ft_put_error("Multiple ceiling color inputs\n", mlx);
    stor = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    while (i > 0)
    {
        ft_printf("s = |%s|\n",s);
        while (*s == ' ')
            s++;
        ft_printf("s = |%s|\n",s);
        color = ft_atoi(s);
        s += ft_intsize(color);
        stor = ft_strjoin(stor, ft_itoa(color));
        ft_printf("color = |%d|\nstor = |%s|\n---------\n",color, stor);
        while (*s == ' ')
            s++;
        ft_printf("s = |%s|\n",s);
        if (*(s++) != ',' && i > 1)
            ft_put_error("Wrong floor color input\n", mlx);
        i--;
    }
    ft_printf("\tThe final color |%s|\n",stor);
    ft_isfloor(s, mlx, type, stor);
    free(stor);
}
```

file `1.cub`:

```
R 1000 750
F 100    ,   100   ,   214
C 135,    197    ,214

EA ./textures/cat4.xpm
NO ./textures/cat1.xpm
SO ./textures/cat2.xpm
WE ./textures/cat3.xpm

S ./textures/barrel.xpm

1000000001
11111111111      100000000100000010111
10000000010000
1111101111
1111101111111111111111111111111111111111111
010000000100000110000000000000000000000001
01000000010000011000000000000000001001000111111111111111111111111111111                     
1111110100000001100000000000000000110000000000000000000000010000001
1000000000000001100000000001111110101111111111111111111110000111101
1111110000000001100000010000000000100001100000100000000000000000001
10000010000000011000000000000100001011000000001111111111111111111111
10000000000       0000000000010000000000010110000000001
100000100000000110000000000000000010110000000111
111111000000000110000000000000010010000000001
100011100000W00000000001111110000010000000001      
1000000000000001100000000   000000000100000000001
1000000000000001100000000000000000100000000001
100000000000000110000000002000000010010000001
10000000000000011000000000000000001000000001
10000000000000011000000000000000001000000001
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

**when I compile all this I get this:**

[image]

In The image :

--> after the floor color is stored and `free(stor)` when starting store the ceiling color the old value in var `stor` stays and add the new data :
[image]

--> after store all the data in `s` and `s = ||` it's get a new data like in the image:
[image]

**I hope you understand what I'm trying to say**

Comment: This question as stated is a lot to wade through, and I'm afraid it is not clear what the problem is. Could you point to a specific place in the code and say what you expected or wanted vs. what actually happened? If possible, make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you. For Your clarifying The problem is fixed look at my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Last if statement:

```
if (*(s++) != ',' && i > 1)
            ft_put_error("Wrong floor color input\n", mlx);
```

I was reading beyond `\0`, so That way all This happened.

for `stor` I was allocated it 2 time:

> The first time in `stor = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);`
>
> The second time when I call `ft_strjoin`.